# How to extract Xtra atom from MP4 file?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

Can one dump/extract the `Xtra` atom from an MP4 file ? I am looking for a solution on a linux system (debian/jessie if possible).

Apparently this atom is used by WMP, as per [link](http://www.ventismedia.com/mantis/view.php?id=12017). I'd like to be able to use such information (rating, publisher or leveling inf) and pass that to my DLNA server (minidlna).

Currently all I see using `AtomicParsley` is:

```
[...]
                     Atom data @ 678585 of size: 529, ends @ 679114
         Atom Xtra @ 679114 of size: 206, ends @ 679320 ~
Atom free @ 679320 of size: 48, ends @ 679368
Atom mdat @ 679368 of size: 248835382, ends @ 249514750

 ~ denotes an unknown atom
[...]
```

And same thing with `MP4Box`:

```
 <UDTARecord Type="Xtra">
 <UnknownBox>
 <BoxInfo Size="206" Type="Xtra"/>
 </UnknownBox>
```

Which cannot be used/parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reported the issue on Debian bug tracker [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=782124), as well as upstream [here](https://bitbucket.org/wez/atomicparsley/issue/45).

Really the only available reference implementation can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/mp4v2/issues/detail?id=113).